# Problems with Image Sprites and jQuery Mobile Ajax navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, caching

I've created an image Sprite for all the images on my jQuery mobile website(e.g. #page1, #page2), 
I thought I could download the image Sprite on #page1 of my site and then I wouldn't need to download it on #page2, But this isn't the case,

Should this work?

Thanks,

I'm doing nothing complex with theses Sprites

e.g.

```
.help-photo {
  width:100px;
  height:112px;
  background:url(help.png) 0px -440px;
}
```

Comment: its cached, but I thought I wouldn't see the request in fireBug reading it.

Comment: Yes its a 304 code, So this is correct behavior? this is great news thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably in inspector you see request which provides respone with `304` http response status code, it is `Not Modified`, and then it does not really dowload the image, so things are right.